# Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

I am trying to add firebase into my android app. It's my first time with firebase. I have followed all the instructions from [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) but I am getting this error

**Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2**

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "..."
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**I have also included below line in build.gradle (project) file**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

Android studio version is 2.1.2
Gradle version 2.10

I have also updated google play services and play repository to latest through SDK manager.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your studio to 3.0 preview and gradle version to

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'

Comment: There's no absolute requirement to upgrade Android Studio.  This question should have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @DougStevenson This is not a duplicate. The solution in the linked question does not solve this issue. Google has some configuration issues with the Firebase 11.2.2 repo. I ended up switching back to 11.2.0